# Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I have windows phone 8.1 XAML project on visual studio 2015 (update 3) after install Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone from this [URL](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb4b3020-9b56-4e81-a314-e40cff00fb52)
I can't found in Extensions Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone 8.1 (XAML). Any idea why?

Comment: can you please write further when you can can't find extension? are you getting any error? or just cannot locate sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct if you install Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone from this [URL](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb4b3020-9b56-4e81-a314-e40cff00fb52). In visual studio Windows Phone 8.1 XAML project：

1. If your project targets **Any CPU**, update your project to use an architecture-specific build output (for example, x86).
2. From the **Solution Explorer** window, right click **References**, and select **Add Reference**…
3. For a Windows Phone 8.1 project: Expand **Windows Phone 8.1**, click **Extensions**, and then select the check box next to **Ad Mediator SDK for Windows Phone 8.1 XAML**.
   [image]
4. Modify the XAML for the page where you are embedding advertising to include the **Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI** namespace. 
   [image]

   More details, please see [Add Microsoft Advertising SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/adcontrol-in-xaml-and--net)